# React-router-dom doesn't render routes defined after a custom component in switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was trying different ways of declaring routes in a modular way. I came across to a strange behaviour:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/1' component={Route1} />
  <ModuleLikeRoutes />
  <Route path='/2' component={Route2} />
</Switch>
```

React router completely ignores /2 and doesn't render Route2. I couldn't find any reason why.
I know I can import a 'module' component like

```
<Route path='/module' component={ModuleComponent} />
```

and probably it's the better way to do it. But I'm just curios how/why it ignores the routes after a custom component. Why I cant render Route2 in the example?

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o4dtrpag/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Switch` will render only one of its children. If the path doesn't match `/1` it will check the second one which is `ModuleLikeRoutes`, and that will be rendered every time, effectively making all components after it meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a bug or a not-supported feature by the library. However, the below code works by order the ModuleLikeRoutes to the last position.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/1' component={Route1} />
  <Route path='/2' component={Route2} />
  <ModuleLikeRoutes />
</Switch>
```